# How to read file paths from a file and create a single combined dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, path

## Required

1- I have a `My_XL_list.txt` file in the current directory that contains paths to the excel files in different folders. I want to pick the first path from that My_XL_list.txt file and make a Data Frame and then pick the **second path of the excel file and** make another Data Frame and then append both Data Frames then pick the third path from .txt file and so on for all of the paths. In the end, I want to make one master excel file for all of those Data Frames.

I am trying something like that which is not giving me the required results. It is returning me an empty excel file.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
path = "rC://Users//Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/*.xlsx"

for f in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_excel(f, index=False, sheet_names='FRJ' )
    all_data = all_data.append(df)


all_data.to_excel('All_Merged_Files.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In order to combine multiple dataframes, create a dataframe for each file, add it to a list and then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine them
- Inside the [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), strip `\n`, filter for files with `'GQH'`, and convert each path to a [`pathlib`](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/) object.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

# path to file
# p = Path('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/My_XL_list.txt')  # update the path to your path
p = Path.cwd() / 'My_XL_list.txt'  # if the file is in the current working directory

# extract all the file paths from the file
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    files = [Path(file.strip()) for file in f.readlines() if 'GQH' in file]

# print(files) if you want
[WindowsPath('C:/Users/Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/names/LT GQH lamas.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/names/LT1011 GQH abc.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/names/LT110011 GQH Bostonx.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/numbers/LT GQH AB.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/numbers/LT101011 GQH Abbots.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/numbers/LT1100011 GQH Boston-g.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/Tums/LT GQH AB.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/Tums/LT1000111 GQH Abbot-L.xlsx'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/Desktop/Stockexchange Q/files/Tums/LT110011 GQH Bostonk.xlsx')]

# create a list of dataframes inside the list-comprehension and concat them together
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f, index=False, sheet_names='FRJ') for f in files])

# save file
df.to_excel('GQH_merged.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you @Trenton McKinney :)